# Standard RecordType selection on the Napili Community page?

Tags: community, profile, record-type, napili

I do have two record types for a custom object. For the User who's having Community User License, I have removed one of them(at the Profile level).

Now on the Napili community's page, I do have a "Record List" standard component which has **New** button on right-top corner for creating new records. When this above user clicks on it, he can still see option for creating either of the record types. Is there anything I need to consider to restrict one of them?

Comment: Are you testing with right user and from the community login ?

Comment: Yes. I have cross checked it more than a couple of times.